# Vertical drawing in lineseries chart

Tags: silverlight, line

Any ideas how to draw not functions (more than one Y for one X) into lineseries chart?

Example: i need to draw points as a line :

- {1,0}
- {0,1}
- {2,4}
- {0,6}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can develop it on your own manually (the hard but more customizable way) adding and drawing lines from point A to B.

Answer (score 0):

You could check out the Silverlight toolkit http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/78435, or buy a third party charting solution.

Answer (score 0):

With this type of data, it is inappropriate to have a line series chart. Use a scatter plot, and possibly include a line of best fit.